# I've got two drop down menus in my navbar and if one is open, it doesn't close if I open another one

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically, I've got two drop down menus in my navbar, and if I open one, and click anywhere it closes (this is fine), but if I open one, and then try to open the next one, the first one stays open and they overlap.

Should I do two different kinds of javascripts for each menu, or should I re-do the whole javascript.. I'm at a loss for words pretty much.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code...

```js
function myFunction() {
 "use strict";
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
 "use strict";
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
} 
function myFunction2() {
 "use strict";
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
 "use strict";
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar select {
 display: none;
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  navbar a { display: none; }
  navbar select { display: inline-block; }
}

.navbar a {
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
 

 <a href="#news">Contact</a>
     <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Services</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Services 1</a>
    <a href="#">Services 2</a>
   </div>
   </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction2()">About</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown2">
      <a href="#">Company</a>
      <a href="#">Map</a>
      <a href="#">Contact numbers</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 <a href="#home">Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
    "use strict";
    var el = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (el.classList.contains('show')) hideDropdown();
        else el.classList.add('show');
}


function myFunction2() {
    "use strict";
    var el = document.getElementById("myDropdown2");
    if (el.classList.contains('show')) hideDropdown();
        else el.classList.add('show');  
}

function hideDropdown() {
    "use strict";
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }   
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    "use strict";
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        hideDropdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem still exists sadly. I'm at a loss for words, this has been bugging me for days. Thanks for trying to help anyways!